# Ruby on Rails - Cron Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache

I am trying to run a cron job on a production Rails application. I don't want to use the "Whenever" gem for running cron jobs. I also don't want to use rails runner due to having to load the entire rails app each time the cron executes.

The code I want to execute every 30 minutes looks something like this:

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord

    def self.send_reminder
        send_reminder_email("example@example.com")
    end
end
```

Comment: Clockwork is awesome -- and you don't have to load the whole app to use it! https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork

Comment: If you're deployed on heroku, heroku has a scheduler add on which you can consider using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I researched this very scenario just last week.  At first I was using [Crono](https://github.com/plashchynski/crono) because it seemed active.  I had problems with this in production however, so I switched to [Clockwork](https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork), a gem I had used previously but seemed a little inactive.  It still works great in Rails 5.

What I like about Clockwork is that it doesn't rely on Unix `cron` (therefore Heroku-friendly) and is very lightweight -- it just takes a single thread and if you need the entire Rails app, you just have to load it once when the Clockwork thread starts up, not every time a task runs.

Here is how it would look with your code:

```ruby
# config/clockwork.rb

require_relative 'boot'
require_relative 'environment'
# The above 2 lines load your Rails app once and allows
# you to call methods on your models.
require 'clockwork'

every(30.minutes, 'send cart reminder') { Cart.send_reminder }
```

And your Procfile, to start the Clockwork scheduler:

```
# Procfile
web: bundle exec rails s # Or whatever you do
scheduler: bundle exec clockwork config/clockwork.rb
```

If you use Heroku, be sure to only spawn one dyno for `scheduler`.  Clockwork only needs one thread and if you try to use more you might get duplicate executions.  Clockwork works best as a scheduler for queueing jobs in another job handler like Sidekiq.